# How to solve null values being transformed (or not) for JSON post by the modelbinder

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I've been struggling with an Action all day.  For some reason I cannot seem to get the model binder to accept some incoming JSON in my application although when I setup a test application and pass in the same JSON the model binder has no issues.

The model looks like this:

```
public class AdjustmentDefaultsModel
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<AdjustmentDefault> Adjustments { get; set; }
}

public class AdjustmentDefault
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentTargetTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentTargetId { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentTargetTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentTargetDescription { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

For completeness, here is my action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddAdjustmentDefaults(AdjustmentDefaultsModel adjustments)
    {
        // will be more code here when I get the model in properly
        return Json(null);
    }
```

The post being done by Ajax in both my main project and my tester project are configured the similarly, the only differences being the url.  The data in the tester is assigned the JSON directly whereas the real project's data is built via knockout:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Employee/AddAdjustmentDefaults',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: ko.toJSON(self),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) { alert("Saved."); },
                error: function (error) { alert("Error."); },
            });
```

When I ran my main project I captured the failing JSON in Fiddler and pasted it in the test project. As mentioned, the test project had no problems binding.

The following JSON works with my main project and my tester project:

```
{"EmployeeId":"cd930985-d66c-4d25-ae0c-253665242cf0","Adjustments":[]}
```

The model has the EmployeeId GUID properly populated and the Adjustments property is null.

However, when I try adding to the list the model binder bombs out, giving me not only null for the list but also null for the employee Guid as well.

I'm not sure where to debug from here.  It would be nice to know what the model binder was failing to do but I've been unable to capture anything useful in that regard.  Do I have to build a custom model binder in order to get details why this is not working?

**Update**

Per asymptoticFault's comment I went ahead and made a custom model binder for my model.  The code looks like this:

```
public class AdjustmentDefaultsModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return null;    // not JSON request

        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        var incomingData = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingData))
            return null;    // no JSON data

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(incomingData, bindingContext.ModelType);
    }
}
```

Using this model binder my Action now generates the model with all the correct values.

I have *no idea* why this works.  While I haven't downloaded the DefaultModelBinder source to verify, it seems to me the that this is basically what it should be doing.  After all, the DefaultModelBinder seems to work for the vast majority of incoming JSON... so why not this one?

So my actual question is still not really answered but I can't waste too much more time on this issue as it consumed about 6 hours more time on this task then the budgeted 10 minutes I had originally estimated.  (sigh.)

Comment: have you tried: JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(self))

Comment: I have tried that as it was recommended in several other answers (in other questions) but it really messed up the JSON in Fiddler and had the same result when it got to the action.  As-is, the Fiddler shows the JSON rather nicely; the TextView is clean and simple and the JSON view is properly formatted.  With stringify the TextView is almost unreadable and the JSON view is not even populated.

Comment: A custom model binder would be a good idea if perhaps only for debugging purposes.  It would allow you to see exactly what value the server is receiving before attempting to turn it into a particular type.  I would also use a browser debugger, I like Chrome's, to see what the value is before it is sent to the server just to verify nothing strange is happening in between.

Comment: Ya, I was *really* hoping to avoid having to build the custom binder.  I'm using Fiddler to see what come's out of Chrome.  If Fiddler showed bad data then I'd backup to the Javascript as the problem... but Fiddler is showing some fine-looking data.

Comment: Custom model binders are actually exceptionally easy to implement and I can provide an example if you would like.

Comment: I've done it before, albeit several years ago (MVC 2).  If you have a link you find exceptional for ASP.NET MVC 4 that's be great, but otherwise I'm sure Google can help find a modern example.

Comment: I don't have a link but it is really just two steps in MVC 4.  1)  Create a class that implements the `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder` interface, I believe it is just the one method `BindModel`.  2)  Add the binder in the Global.asax.cs `OnApplicationStart` method like so, `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(AdjustmentDefaultsModel), new YourModelBinder());` .

Comment: Have you tried passing: data: { adjustments: ko.toJSON(self) },.... ? ... Or using { adjustments: JSON.stringify(..) } ? If I remember correctly I had this issue and you must pass the Action method argument name in the ajax call.

Comment: @asymptoticFault, I added a custom model binder and it solved the problem. I still have no idea *why* it happened, but if you post your comment as an Answer I will accept it since it seems a custom binder is the only way to debug this.  I'll update my question with what I did.

Comment: @SailingJudo - did you try adding the parameter name to the data: {} element in javascript? I'm pretty sure you must have that otherwise it will not bind. It looks like you have a solution but it seems very over complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a custom model binder, it may not ultimately be necessary but it will help you debug what is actually happening with the value passed to the server.

It is a very easy process and is really just two steps:

1) Create a class that implements the `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder` interface, I believe it is just the one method, `BindModel()`.

2) Add the binder in the `OnApplicationStart()` method of the `Global.asax.cs` like so

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(AdjustmentDefaultsModel), new YourModelBinder());
```